# Why gas price so high in erc20 tx?

Tags: erc-20

I know normal gas price is 1gwei(https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4b0aaea87288a1080288187d99c666749577801014535f879d5d85719866ddeb).

But why transaction in erc20 is 6gwei or 30gwei (https://etherscan.io/tx/0xec5b8ff681d02e62cf151186b0fabfe097ec3c8a27dd85be8952410ca917f8f5).

Can I send transastion in erc20 with gasprice=1gwei?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sender of the transaction chooses the gas price they use, so yes, you can send any type of transaction you want with any gas price you choose.

Generally, the higher the gas price you use, the sooner your transaction will get mined. https://ethgasstation.info/ is a good resource for seeing what a good gas price is right now based on existing activity in the network.

Comment: So if I send with 1gwei of a erc20 tx ,it will be seen in block success in final but wait a long time to be in block.

Comment: Yes, if a lot of other people are using higher gas prices, then 1 gwei might mean you have to wait a bit.